# C++ wait without freezing

Tags: c++, sdl

I wrote a programm in C++ that should display a picture (with SDL), then waits 10 seconds and load the next picture.
When I use `Sleep(10000)` the program freezes and doesn't react. 
When I use something like:

```
void Wait ( short Seconds )
{
  clock_t WaitTime = clock( ) + Seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  while( clock( ) < WaitTime )
  {

  }
}
```

the same thing happens. Is there a possibility to just wait 10 seconds without the window freezing?

Comment: Possibly use a timer? http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer

Comment: This is too broad because you need to learn how scheduling (and possibly threading) works! Right now you're just busy-waiting which is a very naive and very power-hungry operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [timer](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer) and pump the message queue using `SDL_WaitEvents()` until the timer fires:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

void MySleep( Uint32 interval )
{
    struct Container
    {
        static Uint32 TimerCallback( Uint32 interval, void* param )
        {
            SDL_Event event;
            event.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
            event.user.code = 42;
            SDL_PushEvent( &event );
            return 0;
        }
    };

    SDL_AddTimer( interval, Container::TimerCallback, NULL );

    SDL_Event event;
    while( SDL_WaitEvent( &event ) )
    {
        if( event.type == SDL_USEREVENT && event.user.code == 42 )
            break;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow
        ( 
        "SDL2",       
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640, 480,                    
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN        
        );

    MySleep( 10000 );

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window ); 

    SDL_Quit(); 
    return 0;   
}
```

Depending on what you mean by "doesn't react" you might have to add the userevent checking to your main event loop instead.